# MobileFirst Android App and MobileFirst Console deployment not working on TLS 1.2

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, websphere, tls1.2, mobilefirst-server

I'm developing an Hybrid MobileFirst application and connecting to a Mobilefirst server in a WebSphere Application Server.

It was required for the server to which the application is connecting to update ssl certificates to TLS 1.2.

Since then, My application is experiencing this issues that I can't solve:

- Not able to deploy any .wlapp file in the MobileFirst console. The file uploads perfectly but when it deploys the following error shows in the logs

  ```
  IOException:peer not authenticated while accessing Worklight artifact
  URL: https://sbybz2211.cloud.dst.ibm.com:9445/wladmin/otu/1.0
  /ffffffdf3c6e30ffffff85ffffffd8ffffffd3ffffffd15c047bffffff900affffffcaffffffa7ffffffbe/
  runtimes/worklight_1/downloads/applications/Temporary317569284/android/2.15
  ```

Any ideas why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

This is a programming Q&A site, so just know that this question is more fitting for a PMR than here...

The following documents is for iOS 9 which requires TLS 1.2 on the server, but since that's what you're trying to setup, you or your IT department should review it: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2015/09/07/preparing-ibm-mobilefirst-platform-server-app-transport-security-ios-9/

Comment: Thanks Idan! I realized that I was only experiencing the issue of the console. The Android version seemed to be working again. Is still fitting more a PMR? Because in that case I will delete this entry

Comment: Questions that are not programming-oriented are always at jeopardy to get closed by the stack overflow  community.